# C# Check if controls are a value that I can take in a physical board

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, if-statement, methods

I've been working on this for a bit, and I've been stuck at this one spot, I can't figure out a way to count the points in the board...

So, first of all, this is a part of the code that makes the cases, in which my tokens are in:

`class Case:Control
    {
        public Point Position { get; set; }`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the dimensions for the cases
    /// </summary>
    public Case()
    {
        MaximumSize = new Size(50, 50);
        MinimumSize = new Size(50, 50);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the background for the cases
    /// </summary>
    public enum DifferentCase
    {
        Dark,
        Pale,
        Brown
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the tokens
    /// </summary>
    public enum Token
    {
        Nothing,
        White,
        Black
    }

    public DifferentCase ColorCase { get; set; }

    public Token ColorToken { get; set; }

    public bool IsBlack { get; set; }
```

And those being my tokens, I have a method that I'm trying to make that counts how many tokens are black and how many are white:

```
private void CheckPoints(Case cases)
    {
        foreach (Case case_ in cases.Controls)
        {
            if (case_.ColorToken == Case.Token.Black)
            {
                _player1Points++;
                lbl_player1Points.Text = _player1Points.ToString();
            }
            else if (case_.ColorToken == Case.Token.White)
            {
                _player2Points++;
                lbl_player2Points.Text = _player2Points.ToString();
            }

        }
    }
```

But when I try to call that method in like this: CheckPoints() for example, if I'm clicking on of those cases, it tells me that "There is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter "cases" of 'frm_othello.CheckPoints(Case)'"

I don't know if the code that I put in that method is good, neither I don't know why I cant call that method in.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can't call `CheckPoints();` with no arguments.  You have defined it with a parameter `Case`

so you need to do `CheckPoints(cases)`  or whatever is the name of the variable / property / field that has cases